# Newrelic intrumentation slows down initialization of Grails services

Tags: performance, grails, newrelic, instrumentation

My application has many services, these are descendants from generic super class, each of them have many methods. Services are lazy loaded by default.

When I use [Newrelic](http://newrelic.com/) to log events in the app, then first use of some controllers dramatically slows down. This happens only for first use of controllers, so I guess it is caused by the instrumentation of lazy loaded services injected into controllers. More services injected means the slower initialization.

How to speed up the Newrelic instrumentation?

Is it possible to instrument only some classes in Newrelic?

Answer (score 0):

The New Relic agent is running and instrumenting as fast as possible when you have it running with your application.  However you could disable parts of the agent to reduce overhead, but they would give you less functionality and odds are it would not give you the results you are expecting.  A good place to bring this up is the New Relic Community Forums http://discuss.newrelic.com, you may get more information there on this from other users.